# AES-GCM decryption rejecting promise

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes

I have a string which I would like to encrypt with AES-GCM using the JavaScript Web Cryptography API. I'm able to encrypt it OK, but when I go to decrypt it the promise gets rejected and I'm not getting a vary descriptive error message.

```
    function aes_encrypt(key, IV, data){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
            {
                name: "AES-GCM",

                //Don't re-use initialization vectors!
                //Always generate a new iv every time your encrypt!
                //Recommended to use 12 bytes length
                iv: sta(IV),

                //Tag length (optional)
                tagLength: 128, //can be 32, 64, 96, 104, 112, 120 or 128 (default)
            },
            key, //from generateKey or importKey above
            sta(data) //ArrayBuffer of data you want to encrypt
            )
            .then(function(encrypted){
                //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the encrypted data
                resolve(ats(encrypted));
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }

    function aes_decrypt(key, IV, data){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
            {
                name: "AES-GCM",
                iv: sta(IV), //The initialization vector you used to encrypt
                tagLength: 128 //The tagLength you used to encrypt (if any)
            },
            key, //from generateKey or importKey above
            sta(data) //ArrayBuffer of the data
            )
            .then(function(decrypted){
                //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the decrypted data
                alert(decrypted);
                resolve(ats(new Uint8Array(decrypted)));
                //resolve(ats(decrypted));
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }



    function ecdh_generate_keypair(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
                {
                    name: "ECDH",
                    namedCurve: "P-384" //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
                },
                true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
                ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"] //can be any combination of "deriveKey" and "deriveBits"
            )
            .then(function(key){
                //returns a keypair object
                resolve(key);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }

    function ecdh_export(key){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
                "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "raw" (public only), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
                key //can be a publicKey or privateKey, as long as extractable was true
            )
            .then(function(keydata){
                //returns the exported key data
                resolve(keydata);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }

    function ecdh_import(key){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
                "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "raw" (public only), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
                key,
                {   //these are the algorithm options
                    name: "ECDH",
                    namedCurve: "P-384", //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
                },
                true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
                ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"] //"deriveKey" and/or "deriveBits" for private keys only (just put an empty list if importing a public key)
            )
            .then(function(privateKey){
                //returns a privateKey (or publicKey if you are importing a public key)
                resolve(privateKey);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }

    function ecdh_derive_key(pub, priv){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
            {
                name: "ECDH",
                namedCurve: "P-384", //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
                public: pub, //an ECDH public key from generateKey or importKey
            },
            priv, //your ECDH private key from generateKey or importKey
            { //the key type you want to create based on the derived bits
                name: "AES-GCM", //can be any AES algorithm ("AES-CTR", "AES-GCM", "AES-CMAC", "AES-GCM", "AES-CFB", "AES-KW", "ECDH", "DH", or "HMAC")
                //the generateKey parameters for that type of algorithm
                length: 256, //can be  128, 192, or 256
            },
            true, //whether the derived key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
            ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //limited to the options in that algorithm's importKey
            )
            .then(function(keydata){
                //returns the exported key data
                resolve(keydata);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
    }

    function random_characters(amount){
        var text = "";
        var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

        for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++){
            text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
        }

        return text;
    }

    // string-to-arraybuffer
    function sta(data){
        var enc = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
        return enc.encode(data);
    }

    // arraybuffer-to-string
    function ats(data){
        var enc = new TextDecoder();
        return enc.decode(data);
    }

    // JSON into and out of the database for cryptokeys
    function json_compress(obj){
        var s = JSON.stringify(obj);
        s = s.replace(/,/g, "♀");
        s = s.replace(/{/g, "☺");
        s = s.replace(/}/g, "☻");
        return s;
    }
    function json_decompress(str){
        str = str.replace(/♀/g, ",");
        str = str.replace(/☺/g, "{");
        str = str.replace(/☻/g, "}");
        return JSON.parse(str);
    }

    ecdh_generate_keypair().then(function(key){
        ecdh_generate_keypair().then(function(key2){
            ecdh_derive_key(key2.publicKey, key.privateKey).then(function(aeskey){
                var m = "Hello World!";
                aes_encrypt(aeskey, "abcdefghijkl", m).then(function(c){
                    alert(c);
                    aes_decrypt(aeskey, "abcdefghijkl", c).then(function(r){
                        alert(r);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I'm aware that hard-coding the IV for AES is a security risk, but I'm just trying to get this working for testing purposes. Any help you can offer is much appreciated, as this has been bugging me all day. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: adding the Chrome debug error message

```
cryptofunctions.js:48 DOMException
(anonymous) @ cryptofunctions.js:48
Promise rejected (async)
(anonymous) @ cryptofunctions.js:47
aes_decrypt @ cryptofunctions.js:31
(anonymous) @ cryptofunctions.js:184
Promise resolved (async)
(anonymous) @ cryptofunctions.js:182
Promise resolved (async)
(anonymous) @ cryptofunctions.js:180
Promise resolved (async)
(anonymous) @ cryptofunctions.js:179
Promise resolved (async)
(anonymous) @ cryptofunctions.js:178
```

EDIT 2: Decided to post the entire file as it all seems relevant to the question.

Comment: Even though it may not be "very descriptive" for you, could you quote this error message? What is `sta`? Can you provide an [MCVE]? (emphasis on **Complete**)

Comment: @Kaiido err is a variable passed to the function when it is called and an error message is printed I think. sta and ats convert from string to arrayBuffer and arraybuffer respectively. Editing to provide further details.

Comment: Where is `.importKey()` called?

Comment: What is `key`? Note, no value is returned from `ecdh_derive_key()` call

Comment: @guest271314 let me just paste in the entire file. I was hesitant to do so originally because it was a lot but I think the entire thing is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Exceptions The promise is rejected when the following exceptions are
>   encountered:
>
> InvalidAccessError when the requested operation is not valid for the
>   provided key (e.g. invalid encryption algorithm, or invalid key for
>   specified encryption algorithm).

Pass `encrypted` to `resolve()` at `aes_encrypt()` call and pass `data` at `aes_decrypt()` call instead of `sta(data)` as `data` is already an `ArrayBuffer` within `aes_decrypt` function

```js
function aes_encrypt(key, IV, data) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.encrypt({
        name: "AES-GCM",

        //Don't re-use initialization vectors!
        //Always generate a new iv every time your encrypt!
        //Recommended to use 12 bytes length
        iv: sta(IV),

        //Tag length (optional)
        tagLength: 128, //can be 32, 64, 96, 104, 112, 120 or 128 (default)
      },
      key, //from generateKey or importKey above
      sta(data) //ArrayBuffer of data you want to encrypt
    )
    .then(function(encrypted) {
      //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the encrypted data
      return encrypted;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function aes_decrypt(key, IV, data) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.decrypt({
        name: "AES-GCM",
        iv: sta(IV), //The initialization vector you used to encrypt
        tagLength: 128 //The tagLength you used to encrypt (if any)
      },
      key, //from generateKey or importKey above
      data //ArrayBuffer of the data
    )
    .then(function(decrypted) {
      //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the decrypted data
      // alert(decrypted);
      return ats(new Uint8Array(decrypted));
      //resolve(ats(decrypted));
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}



function ecdh_generate_keypair() {
  return window.crypto.subtle.generateKey({
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-384" //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
      },
      true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
      ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"] //can be any combination of "deriveKey" and "deriveBits"
    )
    .then(function(key) {
      //returns a keypair object
      return key;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function ecdh_export(key) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
      "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "raw" (public only), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
      key //can be a publicKey or privateKey, as long as extractable was true
    )
    .then(function(keydata) {
      //returns the exported key data
      return keydata;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function ecdh_import(key) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "jwk", //can be "jwk" (public or private), "raw" (public only), "spki" (public only), or "pkcs8" (private only)
      key, { //these are the algorithm options
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-384", //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
      },
      true, //whether the key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
      ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"] //"deriveKey" and/or "deriveBits" for private keys only (just put an empty list if importing a public key)
    )
    .then(function(privateKey) {
      //returns a privateKey (or publicKey if you are importing a public key)
      return privateKey;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function ecdh_derive_key(pub, priv) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey({
        name: "ECDH",
        namedCurve: "P-384", //can be "P-256", "P-384", or "P-521"
        public: pub, //an ECDH public key from generateKey or importKey
      },
      priv, //your ECDH private key from generateKey or importKey
      { //the key type you want to create based on the derived bits
        name: "AES-GCM", //can be any AES algorithm ("AES-CTR", "AES-GCM", "AES-CMAC", "AES-GCM", "AES-CFB", "AES-KW", "ECDH", "DH", or "HMAC")
        //the generateKey parameters for that type of algorithm
        length: 256, //can be  128, 192, or 256
      },
      true, //whether the derived key is extractable (i.e. can be used in exportKey)
      ["encrypt", "decrypt"] //limited to the options in that algorithm's importKey
    )
    .then(function(keydata) {
      //returns the exported key data
      return keydata;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
}

function random_characters(amount) {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }

  return text;
}

// string-to-arraybuffer
function sta(data) {
  var enc = new TextEncoder("utf-8");
  return enc.encode(data);
}

// arraybuffer-to-string
function ats(data) {
  var enc = new TextDecoder();
  return enc.decode(data);
}

// JSON into and out of the database for cryptokeys
function json_compress(obj) {
  var s = JSON.stringify(obj);
  s = s.replace(/,/g, "♀");
  s = s.replace(/{/g, "☺");
  s = s.replace(/}/g, "☻");
  return s;
}

function json_decompress(str) {
  str = str.replace(/♀/g, ",");
  str = str.replace(/☺/g, "{");
  str = str.replace(/☻/g, "}");
  return JSON.parse(str);
}

ecdh_generate_keypair().then(function(key) {
  ecdh_generate_keypair().then(function(key2) {
    ecdh_derive_key(key2.publicKey, key.privateKey).then(function(aeskey) {
      var m = "Hello World!";
      aes_encrypt(aeskey, "abcdefghijkl", m).then(function(c) {
        // alert(c);
        aes_decrypt(aeskey, "abcdefghijkl", c).then(function(r) {
          alert(r);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Note `Promise` constructor is not necessary.

Comment: how can this be eliminated?

Comment: @TyEverett How can what be eliminated?